# Python 3 : How to split a string for a range of characters?

Tags: string, python-3.x

I wish to split a string wherever an uppercase character occurs.
for eg-
if string is StackOverflow
the split should give me ['Stack' , 'Overflow'] 
The words may or may not be in a list but should be separate.
How do i do this?

**EDIT :**

How to do this without regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the `re` module and use *regex*:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'StackOverflow')
['Stack', 'Overflow']
```

*Explanation*:

- Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]`

  - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A (ASCII 65) and Z (ASCII 90) (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^A-Z]*`

  - `^` means beggining of a string
  - `*` quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) A-Z a single character in the range between A (ASCII 65) and Z (ASCII 90) (case sensitive)

Comment: Can you explain what `'[A-Z][^A-Z]*'` does ? I am fairly new to regex but i do understand what [] , ^ and * do individually.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: What part of `[^A-Z]*` is the `not` portion. In other words, what part of the above tells it `not` to match from A-Z

Comment: Simply, `[A-Z]` means "the word begins with an uppercase letter" and `[^A-Z]` means - "followed by 0 or more (`*`) lowercase letters".